# Jquery: scrollTop() is not set to a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to scroll the page to the ajax loader gif in the page on the click of a link.
As shown below i am trying to scroll to the div with id "divWaitImage" 
However scrollTop used below is not working when given the variable offs as parm.

```
var offS = $("#divWaitImage").offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: offS}, 'slow');
```

However it works if i pass in a hardcoded value:

```
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 500}, 'slow');
```

Can anyone please point out the error or a workaround , i am sure its something that i have missed.

thanks for any pointers in advance!

Comment: There's no obvious error in this specific part. Did you look at what's inside offS ? See [Using the console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console). You might also want to put a breakpoint to debug.

Comment: try `var offS = $('#divWaitImage').offset().top || 100;` or check if there is a numeric value inside your variable with `if (isNaN(offS)){ alert('No numeric value'); }`

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle.net example with your problem.

Comment: @dystroy yes i have put offS in watch and evaluated it , it gives the right value as expected as well, this is really weird.

Comment: @user3218288 Either you show more code or you provide a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com).

Comment: Well works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kwXLC/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MSdb4/ - you must have the javascript either 1) above the markup ( move it under the markup ) or 2) Do not have enough height in the page to actually scroll

Comment: @RobSedgwick i do have it under the markup , but will check if the second condition is occurring.

Comment: @RobSedgwick  Hmm, thats the answer i guess, when i do the following:
var offS = 500;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: offS}, 'slow');
it works , so then i might have to put a proper condition in place of 
var offS = $("#divWaitImage").offset().top;

Answer (score 0):

According to your current question this might be a good approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/rRsM4/1/

This is not true -> You need to make sure that you have a height set in the parent container. You can remove the height.

Updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/floradu88/rRsM4/2/

Html:

```
<div style="height:1500px;">
    <img src="http://linux.m2osw.com/sites/linux.m2osw.com/files/images/waiting-wheel-300x300.gif" alt="image" style="margin-top:1000px;" id="divWaitImage"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var offS = $("#divWaitImage").offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: offS}, 'slow');
```

P.S. I will update the answer if you provide updates to your question.

Comment: Thats not true. See it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/kwXLC/2/ without height of container.

Comment: You are right, forgot to edit the answer. Thanks @VedantTerkar